# django admin model for non superuser missing

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django (1.11.1) project with different apps and models.

myproject

- app1

  - models.py
  - admin.py
- app2

  - models.py
  - admin.py

In the django admin this is resolved correctly when logged in as superuser

- Authentifizierung und Autorisierung

  - Benutzer (User)
  - Gruppen (Groups)
- App1

  - App1_model1
  - App1_model2
- App2

  - App2_model1
  - App2_model2

Now I created a group1 and I wanted to grant permissons to app1 for user1 in that group. But even if I grant all availible permissions to group1, when user1 is logged in to the admin he only sees

- Authentifizierung und Autorisierung

  - Benutzer (User)
  - Gruppen (Groups)
- App2

  - App2_model1
  - App2_model2

but App1 is missing.

I also noticed that in the permissions, all permissions start with app2: app2|permission1_app2, app2|permission2_app2, app2|permission1_app1, app2|permission2_app1, ...

in App1 models.py, I import models from App2 that are foreign key fields

`models.py
from django.db import models
from app2.models import App2_model1, ...
class App1Model1(models.Model):
    app2_model1 = models.ForeignKey(App2_model1, ...`

Any ideas how to fix this?

[Edit:] if I put the App1_model1 in the models.py file off App2 as App2_model3 and register it in the admin.py of App2 everything works as expected. The user1 now has the model in the admin (under App2_model3). So apperently when granting permissions to users or groups in Django, you can not have cross app models?!

Comment: Do you grant all permissions through the Django admin interface ?

Comment: yes, I tried also to grant all permissions to the user direktly (throught admin interface) - same result

Comment: Have you register all apps necessary in admin.py file? like: admin.site.register(YourModel)

Comment: yes, otherwise they would not be availible for the superuser in the admin interface